# Go cannot create global byte slice from string

Tags: go

I am trying to make a global byte array from a string with:

```
var operators = []byte {"+-*/%"}
```

however, I am getting the error

```
cannot use string("+-*/") (type untyped string) as type byte in array or slice literal
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to convert a string to a slice of bytes. Note the use of `()` instead of `{}`.

```
 var operators = []byte("+-*/%")
```

The code in the question is a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals).

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this instead

```
var operators = []byte("Hello World")
```

In your code you are trying to literally put a string inside of a byte array as a member, you cannot do that. The error helps you out a bit here by saying it can't use your string as type byte (because it isn't a byte, it is a string).

Comment: I am using operators as a global variable, so I cannot declare the variable that way.

Comment: Sorry, in my haste I didn't notice as I just tried to provide a quick example, but the type conversion still stands